# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} e^{\frac{y}{x}} d x d y$ (Fubini's Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

- Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} e^{\frac{y}{x}} d x d y$.

My attempt.

[image]

Note that $\{0\leq y\leq 1, y\leq x\leq 1\}$ then $\{0\leq  x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq x\}$. So since region is compact and $f$ is continuous, so $f$ is bounded then we can use Fubini's theorem:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} e^{y/x} dy dx$$

**May you check my attempt and may you check my proof-writing?** Thanks...

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst $e^{y/x}$ is not bounded?

Comment: What have done is correct. But for the sake of clarity you can mention that $x>y$ in the region so $0<e^{y/x} <1$.

Comment: Yes exactly, $e^{y/x}<e^1$ here (as I make it)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I think $0<e^{y / x}<1$, is it true?

Comment: how about when $y=1$ and $x=1$. Either way it is absolutely integrable over this domain

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Thanks....

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst How can I show the integral exist?

Comment: It exists because continuous functions are measurable. If you mean show it is finite, the fact that $\int_0^1 \int_0^x e^{y/x}dy dx <\infty$ is enough (fubini-tonelli theorem)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst We didn't do Fubini-Tonelli theorem at the class, can we show from other theorem?

Comment: @JamesEnsor Aposotol's book has a proof of the analog of Fubini's Theorem for Riemann integrable functions on a rectangle. . [It is Theorem 10-20 in the edition I have].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $0\leq y\leq x$ the integrand is $\leq1$, except at $(0,0)$, where it is undefined. Therefore we can use Fubini. But we are going to integrate first with respect to $y$, then with respect to $x$, and obtain
$$\eqalign{\int_0^1\int_y^1 e^{y/x}\> dx\> dy&=\int_0^1\int_0^x e^{y/x}\> dy\> dx\cr &=\int_0^1\left(x e^{y/x}\right)\biggr|_{y=0}^{y=x}\>dx=\int_0^1 x(e-1)\>dx\cr &={1\over2}(e-1)\ .\cr}$$